# Keras LSTM shape doesn't contain length of sequence

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I ran the following code

```
from keras import layers

input_shape = (1000, 10)
x = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
print(x.shape)

lstm1 = layers.LSTM(input_shape=input_shape, units=50, return_sequences=True)
y = lstm1(x)
print(y.shape)
```

and got

```
(?, 1000, 10)
(?, ?, 50)
```

Why does first before last dimension of `y` is `?`? Why isn't it `1000`? Shouldn't LSTM layer with `return_sequences=True` repeat the same number of outputs?

Comment: Tensorflow's native keras implementation gives the actual shape: (?, 1000, 50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does repeat, but the way Keras and Tensorflow communicate is something we don't need to worry about, unless you're doing a very deep research on something.

You can always invoke `keras.backend.int_shape(y)` to see the shapes Keras considers.
You can also invoke `model.summary()` to see the shapes.

Notice that `.shape` is a Tensorflow attribute, not a Keras attribute.

Although you see `?` in there, it's 1000 indeed.